# Make sudo modprobe rtbth auto load at start-up

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, blueman

I have to enter `sudo modprobe rtbth` every time to get my Bluetooth to work properly otherwise Bluetooth menu options are greyed out and do not work.
I have added `modprobe rtbth` into autostart LXQT session settings, but this does not help. How can I make `sudo modprobe rtbth` auto load at start-up PLEASE.

I am using Lubuntu 20.04 Blueman Bluetooth.

Comment: rtbth already added to /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf

Comment: rtbth already added to /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf  and  /etc/modules  Found (blacklist rtbth) in /etc/modprobe.d/rtbth-dkms.conf  Removed the word blacklist and all works ok now thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`.

Use vi or nano to edit the file and add `rtbth` at the end on a new line. Remove what you add from autostart and reboot. The module will then load automatically.

edit:

Or

```
echo rtbth | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Extra edit:

Also make sure there is no `blacklist rtbth` in `/etc/modules` and `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
 grep -F 'blacklist rtbth' /etc/modules && grep -F 'blacklist rtbth' /etc/modules/*
```

Comment: Would it also work to add it to `/etc/modules` with echo?

Comment: That is the old method IIRC? Yeah it will

Comment: LOL! Hey, I'm old! I shall propose it as another answer.

Comment: @chili555 you where not quick enough :+